# wxThread::Delete hangs forever

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

I'm trying to create a multithreaded wxWidgets application using the wxThreadHelper mixin. I'm working on Windows, but the whole idea was to be platform independent. I'm basically following the online examples, but there must be something I don't understand, since as soon as I call the `Delete()` function, the application hangs, waiting forever. The problem is that it appears that the secondary thread hangs also. Do you have any idea on what is it that I'm missing?

This is as minimal as I could get:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

class TestFrame: public wxFrame, public wxThreadHelper {
    wxStaticText *m_text_time;
public:
    TestFrame() : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, wxT("Test")),
        m_text_time(new wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, wxNow()))
    {
        if (CreateThread(wxTHREAD_DETACHED) != wxTHREAD_NO_ERROR) {
            wxLogError("Could not create the worker thread!");
            return;
        }
        if (GetThread()->Run() != wxTHREAD_NO_ERROR) {
            wxLogError("Could not run the worker thread!");
            return;
        }
    }
private:
    wxThread::ExitCode Entry() override {
        while (!GetThread()->TestDestroy()) {
            wxSleep(2);
            m_text_time->SetLabel(wxNow());
        }
        return (wxThread::ExitCode)nullptr;
    }

    void OnClose(wxCloseEvent& event) {
        auto t = GetThread();
        if (t) {
            if (t->Delete() != wxTHREAD_NO_ERROR) {
                wxLogMessage("Error: Can't delete the worker thread!");
            }
        }
        event.Skip();
    }

    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

wxDEFINE_EVENT(myEVT_THREAD_UPDATE, wxThreadEvent);

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(TestFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_CLOSE(TestFrame::OnClose)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

class TestApp : public wxApp
{
    wxFrame *m_frame = nullptr;
public:
    bool OnInit() override {
        m_frame = new TestFrame;
        m_frame->Show();
        return true;
    }
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(TestApp)
```

Comment: How do you know it's _forever_?

Comment: [Research](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxThread#Problems_Deleting_a_Thread).

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings *forever* meaning longer than I care to wait for. Unfortunately your  link doesn't solve the hanging. In fact the thread is not a main thread and hangs here:
`WXDWORD wxAppTraits::DoSimpleWaitForThread(WXHANDLE hThread)
{
    return ::WaitForSingleObject((HANDLE)hThread, INFINITE);
}
`

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings it seems the thread is not running anymore as soon as I call the Delete()... why?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues here.  To answer the main question of why this hangs your program, in the `OnClose` method you call `Destroy()` and then delete the frame (which includes `m_text_time`).  Meanwhile, your thread is sleeping and when it wakes up, it will try change the label for `m_text_time` which no longer exists.  I'm not sure why this causes deadlock instead of a segfault, but this is the problem.  So you can make this work poorly and problematically by simply changing the order to:

```
m_text_time->SetLabel(wxNow());
wxSleep(2);
```

But please don't take that as the solution.  There are still many issues here.

---

First, you should never try to access GUI functions from a secondary thread.  Instead of calling `m_text_time->SetLabel(wxNow());` from your thread, you should throw a thread event back to the main thread and have it change the label. I show how to do this below.

Second, for a detached thread, you should never try to access it after calling Run.  If a thread is detached, you should assume that it can stop and delete itself at any time.  So in your `OnClose` method, you should not call `GetThread`.  If you want to use a detached thread, you'll need to completely reformulate the `OnClose`.  But for this example, I think a joinable thread is completely adequate, and the easist change is to change `if (CreateThread(wxTHREAD_DETACHED)...` to `if (CreateThread(wxTHREAD_JOINABLE)...`

Third, sleeping and then using TestDestroy to determine when to exit can result in sluggish performance.  In this case, when you call Destroy in, your thread will still have to wait until it wakes up before it can exit.  A better approach is to have your thread wait until it is signaled for 2 seconds.  If it is signaled, it quits immediately; and if no signal comes it will repeat the loop after 2 seconds.  There are many ways to do this, but I show 1 way to do this with an object called a semaphore below.

Putting all this together, here is a modified version of your code:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

wxDEFINE_EVENT(myEVT_THREAD_UPDATE, wxThreadEvent);

class TestFrame: public wxFrame, public wxThreadHelper {
    wxStaticText *m_text_time;
public:
    TestFrame() : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, wxT("Test")),
        m_text_time(new wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, wxNow()))
    {
        if (CreateThread(wxTHREAD_JOINABLE) != wxTHREAD_NO_ERROR) {
            wxLogError("Could not create the worker thread!");
            return;
        }
        if (GetThread()->Run() != wxTHREAD_NO_ERROR) {
            wxLogError("Could not run the worker thread!");
            return;
        }

        Bind(myEVT_THREAD_UPDATE, &TestFrame::OnThreadUpdate, this);
    }
private:
    wxThread::ExitCode Entry() override {

        while ( !GetThread()->TestDestroy() ) {
            wxThreadEvent* event = new wxThreadEvent(myEVT_THREAD_UPDATE);
            event->SetString(wxNow());
            wxQueueEvent(this,event);

            if ( m_shutdownSemaphore.WaitTimeout(2000) != wxSEMA_TIMEOUT  )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return (wxThread::ExitCode)0;
    }

    void OnClose(wxCloseEvent& event) {
        auto t = GetThread();
        if (t) {
            m_shutdownSemaphore.Post();
            t->Wait();
        }
        event.Skip();
    }

    void OnThreadUpdate(wxThreadEvent& event)
    {
        m_text_time->SetLabel(event.GetString());
    }

    wxSemaphore m_shutdownSemaphore;
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(TestFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_CLOSE(TestFrame::OnClose)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

class TestApp : public wxApp
{
    wxFrame *m_frame = nullptr;
public:
    bool OnInit() override {
        m_frame = new TestFrame;
        m_frame->Show();
        return true;
    }
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(TestApp)
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem was exactly the access to the GUI. I don't think the deadlock was caused by the already destroyed frame, because the OnClose never managed to get past the Delete, but anyway at least now it works. I notice that you used Bind to attach the OnThreadUpdate event. Would it be possible to use the Event Table for that?

Comment: Since myEVT_THREAD_UPDATE is a custom thread event, there is no pretty macro for adding it to an event table.  If you really want to do it, you'll need to use something like: `wx__DECLARE_EVT1(myEVT_THREAD_UPDATE, wxID_ANY, wxThreadEventHandler(TestFrame::OnThreadUpdate))wx__DECLARE_EVT1(myEVT_THREAD_UPDATE, wxID_ANY, wxThreadEventHandler(TestFrame::OnThreadUpdate))`

Comment: Thank you again. Ugly, indeed. The Bind version is definitely clearer!