# WxWidgets C++: Run function that changes label's text every second

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I want to call a function that changes a **label(!)**'s text every second in my app. That is due to those values constantly changing.

Here's a function I made:

```cpp
void refreshStuff(wxStaticText* staticText)
{
    
    
    
    // No need for adding the pause in the question, it's self-explanatory
    while(1) {
       
        int info1 = 15;
        staticText->SetLabel("Current X: " + std::to_string(info1));

    }

    
}
```

This doesn't work due to the fact we're blocking the main thread. Only if it was that easy. Thankfully, SO exists; Mind telling me how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic wxWidgets Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571523/basic-wxwidgets-timer)

Comment: This answer could be related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65375616/6070341

Comment: Hint, change your thinking from "Run function that (changes the label's text every second)" to "(Run function that changes the label's text) every second"

Answer (score 0):

Here you have it, you should use more the `this->` using wx, specially with events.

```
class Frame : public wxFrame {

private:

    wxTimer * timer;
    wxPanel * panel;
    wxBoxSizer * sizer;
    wxStaticText * label;

public:

    int lable_num = 0;
    const int interval = 500;

    Frame() : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "Name"){
        this->sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
        this->panel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
        this->label = new wxStaticText(
            this->panel, wxID_ANY, "Current x: 0"
        );

        this->timer = new wxTimer(this);
        // The bind bust be on the instance parent
        // not the instance of the calle
        this->Bind(wxEVT_TIMER, &Frame::on_timer, this);
        (*this->timer).Start(interval);

        this->sizer->Add(this->panel, 0, wxEXPAND);
        this->SetSizer(sizer);
    }

    ~Frame(){
        (*this->timer).Stop();
    }

    void on_timer(wxTimerEvent& ev) {
        this->label->SetLabel(
            "Current X: " + std::to_string(++lable_num)
        );
    }    

};
```

Comment: What's the point of using more `this->`? And why should one use it with wx specifically?

Comment: @LauriNurmi, I'd guess because (s)he use inline stuff...

Comment: Mainly because wx manages for you the widgets instances and i find it harder to keep track on the middle of the code (especially if you have a nice espagueti) where is the parent or if it is located inside the class. It is not necessary, but i consider it good practice when using wx.

Comment: @Alex, using `this` is C++ syntactic sugar. As long as you follow some coding standard, you can get away without using it

Comment: You can use `this->` if you prefer to, but you never _need_ to use it, so the advice to use "more of it" is misguided. BTW, you also don't need to call `wxTimer::Stop()` manually, the timer will be stopped when it's destroyed anyhow. But this is also harmless, just as using `this->`.

Comment: I would like to use the wxTimer function.  I understand how to set it up and bind it and make the call to update a label box on the form.  The part I'm not getting is how you get info to populate lable_num from outside the Frame class passed into your on_timer function?

Comment: If you need `on_timer()` to access another instance you can pass a pointer in the constructor or add a function that populates a variable if you don´t want to have the variable marked as public; if you just want to have multiple windows "connected", another option is to use a `static` variable in the class (keep in mind that in the example there is only one thread).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use `wxYield()` and `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1))`

```
#include <thread>
#include <wx/wx.h>

class wxMiniApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();

    int info1 = 15;
    wxStaticText* staticText;

    void OnClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
    {
        refreshStuff(staticText);
    }

    void refreshStuff(wxStaticText* staticText)
    {

        while(true) {

            staticText->SetLabel("Current X: " + std::to_string(info1++));

            wxYield();

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    }
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(wxMiniApp);

bool wxMiniApp::OnInit()
{
    SetTopWindow(new wxFrame(NULL, -1, wxT(""), wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(100, 50)));

    new wxButton(GetTopWindow(), wxID_EXIT, wxT("Click!"));

    Connect(wxID_EXIT, wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler(wxMiniApp::OnClick));

    staticText = new wxStaticText(GetTopWindow(), wxID_EXIT, "");

    GetTopWindow()->Show();

    return true;
}
```